# Finding strings in a large text file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

The following is my code:

```
with open("WinUpdates.txt") as f:
    data=[]
    for elem in f:
        data.append(elem)

with open("checked.txt", "w") as f:
    check=True
    for item in data:
        if "KB2982791" in item:
            f.write("KB2982791\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2970228" in item:
            f.write("KB2970228\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2918614" in item:
            f.write("KB2918614\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2993651" in item:
            f.write("KB2993651\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2975719" in item:
            f.write("KB2975719\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2975331" in item:
            f.write("KB2975331\n")
            check=False
        if "KB2506212" in item:
            f.write("KB2506212\n")
            check=False
        if "KB3004394" in item:
            f.write("KB3004394\n")
            check=False
        if "KB3114409" in item:
            f.write("KB3114409\n")
            check=False
        if "KB3114570" in item:
            f.write("KB3114570\n")
            check=False

    if check:
        f.write("No faulty Windows Updates found!")
```

The "WinUpdates.txt" file contains a lot of lines like these:

> http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2980245     RECHTS  Update
>   KB2980245               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   8/18/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2981580     RECHTS  Update
>   KB2981580               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   8/18/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2982378     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2982378               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   9/12/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2984972     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2984972               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   10/17/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2984976     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2984976               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   10/17/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2984981     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2984981               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   10/16/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2985461     RECHTS  Update
>   KB2985461               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   9/12/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2987107     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2987107               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   10/17/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2990214     RECHTS  Update
>   KB2990214               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   4/16/2015
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2991963     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2991963               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   11/14/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2992611     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2992611               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   11/14/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2993651     RECHTS  Update
>   KB2993651               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   8/29/2014
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2993958     RECHTS  Security Update
>   KB2993958               NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM   11/14/2014

But when I execute my code, it says that it has not found any of those updates? Even though I know that it should find 4.
I wrote the "data" list into a new text file, but there it seems everything alright?

Why do you think my code does not work?

Comment: Same as @Math; if I manually add additional "KBxxxxxxx" to the `WinUpdates.txt` file, I get multiple results in `checked.txt`. What output are you getting, and what output do you want?

Comment: The output is "No faulty Windows Updates found!" in the "checked.txt" file, even though it should write four of the checked updates. I wonder if it is the file, the exported WinUpdates.txt that is causing the issues.

Comment: I also get "KB2993651\n" written to "checked.txt" when I run your code. FWIW, there are more compact ways to write this code, but your code _should_ do what you expect. Which 4 KB ids are you expecting to be found?

Comment: Same as @PM2Ring when I copy and paste the code you supplied in the question I get "KB2993651" in `checked.txt`.

Comment: Is the data you've posted here **identical** to the data you're using on your machine? Maybe copy this data back to your hd and run a file diff program to see if something weird has happened. I _guess_ there could be some encoding problem occurring...

Comment: Could you guys try it with this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9rr5nhh8dsgaut/WinUpdates.txt?dl=0

Comment: With the new data I get KB2506212
KB2918614
KB2970228
KB2993651
KB3004394

Comment: Hmm. With new data I get nothing. If I print the file as it's read in I get `[Decode error - output not utf-8]`. So, it looks like a unicode problem. I'm running Python2. @PM2Ring: I'm guessing you're on Python3?

Comment: Well, I copied the content of the file to a new file, and got the expected result, so thanks for that (I am on Python3). Ideally though, the copy and pasting should not be required.

Comment: @SiHa: No, I'm on Python 2.6.6, but I'm using Linux & I pasted the data into a file using the `cat` command in a shell which uses UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: FWIW, the data I got by copy & pasting from dropbox definitely appears to be UTF-8. BTW, I've posted some alternative ways to write your program. Even though it doesn't exactly answer your question I hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, your code can be written in a more compact way that doesn't require a zillion `if` statements. Also, since the (new) data file is only 63342 bytes you can read the whole thing into a single string, rather than into a list of strings.

```
kb_ids = (
    "KB2982791",
    "KB2970228",
    "KB2918614",
    "KB2993651",
    "KB2975719",
    "KB2975331",
    "KB2506212",
    "KB3004394",
    "KB3114409",
    "KB3114570",
)

with open("WinUpdates.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

check = True
with open("checked.txt", "w") as f:
    for kb in kb_ids:
        if kb in data:
            f.write(kb + "\n")
            check = False

    if check:
        fout.write("No faulty Windows Updates found!\n")
```

Contents of **checked.txt**, using the linked data:

```
KB2970228
KB2918614
KB2993651
KB2506212
KB3004394
```

Note that this code prints the found kbids in the order that they're defined in `kb_ids`, rather than the order they occur in "WinUpdates.txt".

Searching through the whole file as a string for each kbid is probably *not* a good idea if the file is large, eg, more than a megabyte or so; you might want to run some timing tests (using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)) to see which strategy works best on your data.

If you want to read a file into a list there's no need to use a `for` loop, you can just do this:

```
with open("WinUpdates.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Alternatively, you can process the file line by line without reading it into a list:

```
kb_ids = (
    "KB2982791",
    "KB2970228",
    "KB2918614",
    "KB2993651",
    "KB2975719",
    "KB2975331",
    "KB2506212",
    "KB3004394",
    "KB3114409",
    "KB3114570",
)

check = True
with open("WinUpdates.txt") as fin:
    with open("checked.txt", "w") as fout:
        for data in fin:
            for kb in kb_ids:
                if kb in data:
                    fout.write(kb + "\n")
                    check = False

        if check:
            fout.write("No faulty Windows Updates found!\n")
```

On more modern versions of Python the two [`with` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) can be combined into a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I added and fixed what you were missing check the two comments to see what I mean. This worked for me so it should work for you. Have a great day!

```
with open("WinUpdates.txt", "r") as f:  #you forgot to put the "r" option to read the file
    data = f.read()  #no reason to put the data into a list a string will do fine

with open("checked.txt", "w") as f:
    check=True
    if "KB2982791" in data:
        f.write("KB2982791\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2970228" in data:
        f.write("KB2970228\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2918614" in data:
        f.write("KB2918614\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2993651" in data:
        f.write("KB2993651\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2975719" in data:
        f.write("KB2975719\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2975331" in data:
        f.write("KB2975331\n")
        check=False
    if "KB2506212" in data:
        f.write("KB2506212\n")
        check=False
    if "KB3004394" in data:
        f.write("KB3004394\n")
        check=False
    if "KB3114409" in data:
        f.write("KB3114409\n")
        check=False
    if "KB3114570" in data:
        f.write("KB3114570\n")
        check=False

    if check:
        f.write("No faulty Windows Updates found!")
```